# StopIteration Error occurs during training while running the train.py file

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, stopiteration

I am trying to run a code from github. The file is called train.py. It is supposed to run a Neural Network for training on a dataset. However, I get the following error

```
(QGN) ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-114:~/QGN$ python train.py
Input arguments:
id               ade20k
arch_encoder     resnet50
arch_decoder     QGN_dense_resnet34
weights_encoder
weights_decoder
fc_dim           2048
list_train       ./data/train_ade20k.odgt
list_val         ./data/validation_ade20k.odgt
root_dataset     ./data/
num_gpus         0
batch_size_per_gpu 2
num_epoch        20
start_epoch      1
epoch_iters      5000
optim            SGD
lr_encoder       0.02
lr_decoder       0.02
lr_pow           0.9
beta1            0.9
weight_decay     0.0001
deep_sup_scale   1.0
prop_weight      2.0
enhance_weight   2.0
fix_bn           0
num_val          500
num_class        150
transform_dict   None
workers          40
imgSize          [300, 375, 450, 525, 600]
imgMaxSize       1000
cropSize         0
padding_constant 32
random_flip      True
seed             1337
ckpt             ./ckpt
disp_iter        20
visualize        False
result           ./result
gpu_id           0
Model ID: ade20k-resnet50-QGN_dense_resnet34-batchSize0-LR_encoder0.02-LR_decoder0.02-epoch20-lossScale1.0-classScale2.0
# samples: 20210
1 Epoch = 5000 iters
Starting Training!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 355, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "train.py", line 217, in main
    train(segmentation_module, iterator_train, optimizers, history, epoch, args)
  File "train.py", line 33, in train
    batch_data = next(iterator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/QGN/lib/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 274, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The code from train.py (lines 211 to 231) is as follows
'''

## Main loop

```
history = {'train': {'epoch': [], 'loss': [], 'acc': []}}

print('Starting Training!')

for epoch in range(args.start_epoch, args.num_epoch + 1):
    train(segmentation_module, iterator_train, optimizers, history, epoch, args)

    # checkpointing
    checkpoint(nets, history, args, epoch)

    # evaluation
    args.weights_encoder = os.path.join(args.ckpt, 'encoder_epoch_' + str(epoch) + '.pth')
    args.weights_decoder = os.path.join(args.ckpt, 'decoder_epoch_' + str(epoch) + '.pth')
    iou = eval_train(args)

    # adaptive class weighting
    adjust_crit_weights(segmentation_module, iou, args)


print('Training Done!')
```

'''

I am not sure if I have shared all the required information. I would appreciate if ant help could be provided to resolve this issue. Just to inform, I have tried using the try and except method as  shared on github on the link https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch/issues/214. However the error still persists.

The code from line 30 in train.py is as follows

```
   # main loop
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(args.epoch_iters):
        batch_data = next(iterator)
        data_time.update(time.time() - tic)

        segmentation_module.zero_grad()
```

I ammended the above code as follows

```
   # main loop
     loader_train = torchdata.DataLoader(
        dataset_train,
        batch_size=args.num_gpus,  # we have modified data_parallel
        shuffle=False,  # we do not use this param
        collate_fn=user_scattered_collate,num_workers=int(args.workers),
        drop_last=True,
        pin_memory=True)


    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(args.epoch_iters):
        try:
            batch_data = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            iterator = iter(loader_train)
            batch_data = next(iterator)
        data_time.update(time.time() - tic)

        segmentation_module.zero_grad()
```

But still no joy. The error still remains.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**
Your `args.epoch_iters` is larger than the number of batches in `loader_train`. Python raises `StopIteration` error when you ask for more batches than there actually are.

When you iterate over some pythonic collection of elements (e.g., list, tuple, `DataLoader`...) python needs to know when it reaches the end of that collection. It is done by raising `StopIteration` exception. `for` loop in python explicitly listens to this exception and uses it to know when to stop. Alas, in your code you do not use a `for` loop over `loader_train`, but rather over `range(args.epoch_iter)` and you use `next(iterator)` to get the batches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I would really appreciate it if you could re-write the code in the comments just as way you have explained.

Comment: changed default values of epoch_iters from 1-5000, but the error still persists
`# samples: 20210
1 Epoch = 1 iters
Starting Training!
# samples: 20210
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 372, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "train.py", line 234, in main
    train(segmentation_module, iterator_train, optimizers, history, epoch, args)
  File "train.py", line 45, in train
    batch_data = next(iterator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/QGN/lib/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 274, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`